# Length of the certificate in complexity classes

Tags: certificate, complexity-theory

> A nondeterministic machine trying to decide membership in a language
>   is presented with a hint (called a "witness" or "certificate") which
>   proves membership (no such witness is provided for elements outside
>   the language; the definition is asymmetric).

So, if a non-deterministic algorithm can solve a problem in O(f(n)) time, does this mean the length of the certificate is f(n)? And the input size is n?

Also, if an algorithm A exists that can verify a certificate in O(f(n)) time, how does this imply the existence of a non-deterministic algorithm that can solve the problem in O(f(n)) time?

Comment: StackOverflow is probably not the right place for this question. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ seems a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

- *So, if a non-deterministic algorithm can solve a problem in O(f(n)) time, does this mean the length of the certificate is f(n)?*

**no**

- *And the input size is n?*

**yes**

- *Also, if an algorithm A exists that can verify a certificate in O(f(n)) time, how does this imply the existence of a non-deterministic algorithm that can solve the problem in O(f(n)) time?*

**No implication here. The statement is that if a non-deterministic algorithm can solve a problem in O(f(n)) and the solution (certificate or whitness if you want) can be verified in O(g(n)) and f and g are polynoms, than the problem is NP hard. (not necessarily NP-complete)**

Comment: I've been given that it directly implies the latter. Would your answer change if A was a deterministic algorithm?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it imply that the certificate size is f(n) since a non-deterministic (luckiest guesser) algorithm would be able to solve it in a minimum the length of the solution by guessing every bit correctly?

Comment: I understand that the length of the certificate will be O(f(n)) :)